# Bootstrap + SASS, как начать работу?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Установил **`SASS`** через консоль, по этому туториалу [sass-scss.ru](https://sass-scss.ru/install/).

В работе мне потребуется **`bootstrap`**.

**Вопрос:**

- Как начать использовать в проекте **`SASS`**, создать файл `style.scss` и писать в него `css` код или нужны дополнительные действия?
- Как правильно подключить `bootstrap` и начать его использовать в проекте?

Сейчас на начальной стадии, `html` код выглядит так:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="ru">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.scss">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/vW51JUVT66w
https://youtu.be/H4cG4tbc-xQ
Сам просвещался тут. ))

Comment: @Rafael Shepard хорошее оформление вопроса.Буду приводить его в пример другим новичкам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно все не так просто, советую посмотреть/почитать гайд по развёртыванию проекта на Gulp/Webpack так как если писать тут выйдет очень много кода. Что бы использовать Sass нужно сначало развернуть NPM + например Webpack.

https://proglib.io/p/webpack-in-15/ - пример,  но в интернете их ещё масса, стоит лишь поискать.

Но для новичка Gulp будет легче в плане понимания.

После того как ты установишь зависимости на свой проект, выполни установку ещё двух пакетов:

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install sass
```

И далее опиши таски в webpack/gulp, опять таки примеров в интернете много.

Будут вопросы пиши:)

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ, вопросов все еще много. Что лучше использовать? и Как быстро стартануть?

Comment: Для начала лучше использовать Gulp, он будет попроще немного чем Webpack, тем более поняв как работает одно ты поймёшь как работает другое. А быстрый старт, я бы порекомендовал  вот эти видеоуроки: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW51JUVT66w  достаточно интересно рассказывает, сам учил Gulp  на них. Помог как смог:) если что пиши, подскажу ещё что.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, от души!) пойду смотреть видео

Comment: Если будут вопросы пиши:)

Answer (score 2):

**1. Вариант:** Использовать webpack или gulp сборщик. Быстро и удобно, но нужно правильно настроить. Примеров сборки в сети достаточно много.

Для gulp сборки выполнить:

```
npm i –g gulp
npm i --save-dev gulp
npm i --save-dev gulp-sass
npm i bootstrap
```

Настроить gulpfile.js.

Подключение bootstrap в style.scss:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

**2. Вариант:** Использовать online конверторы (например [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) ). Минусы - долго и неудобно.

**3. Вариант:** Конвертер с помощью командной строки ruby. Для этого нужно установить [rubyinstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/). Запустить командную строку ruby. Выполнить команды:

```
gem install sass

sass input.scss output.css
```

или

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Comment: Спасибо! По бутстрапу очень полезная инфа, не знал как устроено.